# c# POP3 client implementation

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, tls1.2, pop3

I'm trying to implement a POP3 client in C#, and the authentication using AUTH PLAIN is killing me. I'm using my account on pop3.live.com for testing, but can't get past beyond the authentication. I've tried connecting via SSL over port 995 and regular 110 (then switching to TLS), but can't manage to get authenticated.

I'm using TcpClient class to establish a connection and get a +OK response from the server. When doing a non-SSL connection I check the capabilities with the command CAPA, and get the response STLS. So I send the command STLS, switch to SslStream, send another CAPA command to check for authentication mechanisms and get that SASL PLAIN is supported (which was not in the regular connection).

Now I don't know what to send with AUTH PLAIN - I've tried sending base64 "account\0account@hotmail.com\0password", "\0account@hotmail.com\0password", "\0account\0password" ... all possible combinations, but either get "Protocol error" when sending the credential in line with AUTH PLAIN, or "Unauthorized ..." when sending the credentials after sending AUTH PLAIN (returns "+ " as expected).

Am I missing something? Can anyone provide a example how to authenticate when using SSL/TLS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "\0account@hotmail.com\0password"

Comment: I did try that, but get a "Protocol error. 16", so I'm assuming I've missed something before sending AUTH PLAIN.

Comment: You need to use a byte array to represent that sequence, not a string.

Comment: Yes I am, there is no other way to write to the stream. I've tried different encodings (UTF8, ASCII), with and without conversion to base64, yet no success.

Comment: You need to base64 encode. My PLAIN auth implementation works just fine so you must be doing something else wrong.